# AddThis integration

Tags: integration, this, umbraco, addition, addthis

Hi y'all great developers,

I am trying to integrate AddThis into Umbraco CMS and would like to hear if any of you know how to add it via an IFrame or the like so that a client would be able to see the statistics in the backoffice.

Any suggestions on auto log-in are also welcomed!

Thanks a lot for your help.
Kind regards, Iulia

Answer (score 0):

To add an iframe into an ascx or aspx file is no problem.  So whichever one is preferred there are well trodden steps to customizing the umbraco backoffice to show custom aspx pages or ascx controls.

Adding a new section to the umbraco admin backoffice is pretty well documented.  [If you go through these steps you can have your own section in the backoffice](http://www.geckonewmedia.com/blog/2009/8/3/how-to-create-a-custom-section-in-umbraco-4) - and then simply create an aspx page or pages with whatever content you want to display.

Alternatively you can [change or add a tab to the standard view of backoffice](http://www.softwareassociates.in/blog/how-to-customize-umbraco-dashboard/) and then use an ascx user control to display whatever content you like.

Comment: Yes, I know how to do this in Umbraco :-). My question is more specific and it is about AddThis. So the question is if you have tried to integrate AddThis's statistics in Umbraco (with auto login) so that a logged on user can see them in the backoffice.